# WooCommerce Download Variations dependent on Gravity Forms (WooCommerce Add-on) user input

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, add-on, gravity-forms-plugin, product-variations

I have the following 3 plugins installed and configured:

- Gravity Forms
- WooCommerce
- WooCommerce Gravity Forms Add-On

This combination has already solved many of my problems (variable pricing dependent on user input via multiple options), but there is one issue that I can't seem to directly overcome, and that's providing a customer with a different set of Downloadable files dependent on their customized input.

It seems that the purpose of the Gravity Forms add-on is to eliminate the requirement of administering variations based on potentially hundreds of combinations of WooCommerce defined attributes, which makes a lot of sense and is a big time saver, but it doesn't seem to address variations that extend beyond price; like Downloadable files.

For instance, given my rough sample below:

**Product options, sample (this is a basic variable product, some might be much more complex):**

1. Product Option A
2. Product Option B

Options Dependent on Product A:

- Product-A Option Z
- Product-A Option Y
- Product-A Option X

Options Dependent on Product B:

- Product-B Option Z
- Product-B Option Y
- Product-B Option X

These combinations all yield a different price, which Gravity Forms can cover, but these combinations should also provide a customer with a different combination of PDF downloads (ie: Product Option A.pdf + Product-A Option Y.pdf at $XXX.XX, or Product Option B.pdf + Product-B Option Z.pdf at $XX.XX).

Is there a way to pass a hidden var or shortcode from the Gravity Forms user input that can be defined as an attribute to then set the Downloadable file variations in WooCommerce?

I'm really pulling my hair out here because on one hand this could be handled exclusively using WooCommerce, but the number of variations could be in the hundreds, yet Gravity Forms seems not to have the capacity to send WooCommerce a means of defining much else than calculated price :(

Perhaps I am thinking about this the wrong way and should be using another method. If someone can offer a solution of some form, I would very much appreciate it!

T